# check if div has image inside, then do something

Tags: jquery, addclass

I want to addClass to previous div.local_text if there is an < img> tag inside div.local_logo

```
<div>
    <div class="local_text"></div>
    <div class="local_logo">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far this is not working, is adding class to all `div.local_text` but the previous only.

```
if (jQuery(".local_logo:has(img)")) {
    jQuery(".local_logo").prev(".local_text").addClass("half");
};
```

Comment: Use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, `jQuery(".local_logo:has(img)").prev(".local_text").addClass("half");`

Comment: You don't have an `<img>` inside the div you're looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector

> Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.

```
jQuery(".local_logo:has(img)") // Select all the classes `.local_logo` having img as descendent
    .prev(".local_text").addClass("half");
```

```js
jQuery(".local_logo:has(img)").prev(".local_text").addClass("half");
```

```css
.half {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="local_text">First</div>
  <div class="local_logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="local_text">Second</div>
  <div class="local_logo">
    <a href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="local_text">Third</div>
  <div class="local_logo">
    <img src="" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest:

```
// cache the <div clas="local_text"> elements:
var text = jQuery('.local_text');

// use toggleClass() with a class-name and switch,
// the class-name will be applied to the relevant elements
// if the switch returns a truthy value (0 is falsey):
text.toggleClass('half', text.next('div.local_logo').find('img').length);
```

Note that the question title says you want to add a class if the next `<div>` contains an `<img>` element, whereas the code in the question has `<a>` element.

If there's a mistake somewhere, please adjust the selector within `find()` as appropriate.

References:

- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 0):

try this (use `.find()` method )

```
$('.local_logo div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img').length) {
        // there is an image in this div, do anything here..
    }
});
```

it works for me, hope to solve your problem too :)